# Orthogonality of Chebyshev Second Kind

Tags: special-functions, chebyshev-polynomials, chebyshev-function

I was reading on Chebyshev functions, and I found lots of resources on proving the orthogonality of Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind:

$\int_{-1}^1 T_m(x) T_n(x) \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 
\begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{if $m\neq n$} \\
                                   \pi & \text{if $m=n=0$} \\
                                   \pi/2 & \text{if $m=n\neq 0$}
  \end{cases}$

But I've found no resources on proving the orthogonality for polynomials of the second kind. The resources I've read only say "similarly, we find that:"

$\int_{-1}^1 U_m(x) U_n(x) \sqrt{1-x^2} dx = 
\begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{if $m\neq n$} \\
                                   \pi/2 & \text{if $m=n$}
  \end{cases}$

Does anyone know how to show the above orthogonality explicitly?

Comment: Let $x=\cos\theta$ and recall $U_n(\cos\theta)\sin\theta=\sin[(n+1)\theta]$.

Comment: @user10354138 yes, i realized this shortly after asking the question. I might answer my own question later haha. Thanks btw!